# Curl Request working but not inside laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

Hi everyone i have crul request when i use it in single php page without laravel it work fine but if i  put it inside laraevl controller to use it not working and return code status 0

My Request

```
$data = '{"PaymentInquiryV4RequestMessage":{"RefNum":"123456"}}';                                                               
                                                                                     
                $ch = curl_init('https://b2btest.stcpay.com.sa/B2B.DirectPayment.WebApi/DirectPayment/V4/PaymentInquiry');                                                                      
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                  
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'crt.crt');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, 'key.key');            
                curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                                                       
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
                    'Content-Type: application/json',   
                    'X-ClientCode: XXXXXXXXXXX'
                    )                                                                       
                );                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                     
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                $result = json_decode($result, true);
                print_r ($result);
```

Comment: Not sure what that issue could be but on a side note, if you're using this in a laravel app, I would consider using the Guzzle client instead of using curl directly, see [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client)

Comment: You might try running `print_r ($result);` before the `json_decode`, it could be that you are getting a response but its not valid JSON or there's something in the JSON causing a parsing error.

Comment: @WesleySmith Same error

Comment: try to catch error `if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}`

Comment: @user969068 Nothing returned

Comment: did you echo it? `$result = curl_exec($ch); if (curl_errno($ch)) {     $error_msg = curl_error($ch); } echo $error_msg;`

Comment: @user969068 yes

Comment: no sorry i get this error 

could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory, (no
key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)

Comment: you need to provide full path to your certificate file i.e `'/var/www/certificate/crt.crt'`  and `'/var/www/certificate/key.key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when dealing with curl always start by debugging errors, which you can enable like

```
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
if (curl_errno($ch)) {     
   $error_msg = curl_error($ch); 
   echo $error_msg; 
}
```

and as you mentioned in comment, you received below error after adding above code:

```
could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
```

It clearly indicate it can't find your certificate files, update path to those files in your call , like if your certificates are in directory `/var/www/certificate/`, your code would be

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/var/www/certificate/crt.crt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, '/var/www/certificate/key.key');
```

and make sure cert files are readable by setting proper permissions.

p.s you can also use Laravel helpers to get the path

```
base_path();    // '/var/www/mysite'
app_path();     // '/var/www/mysite/app'
storage_path(); // '/var/www/mysite/storage'
```

so you call will contain like

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, base_path().'/certificate/crt.crt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, base_path().'/certificate/key.key');
```